# Abnormal memory consumption with concurrent MQ JMS listeners in WSO2

Tags: jms, wso2, ibm-mq, wso2-esb

Using WSO2ESB with Websphere MQ JMS transport we had to increase number of concurrent queue listeners one day, for performance reasons. But such change led to the problem with memory consumption, which unexpectedly appeared to be very dependent on the number of concurrent JMS threads.

Herebelow are jvisualvm charts that shows the state of heap while processing the same large message (up to 100M), with the only difference in the number of listeners: 1 in the first case and 32 in the second.

[image] 
[image]

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The receive buffer has to be pre-allocated for each client. It might have a pre-allocated send buffer too, I am not sure. I am going on MQ principles, not this implementation which I dont know that well. Anyhow I would think that is what you are mainly seeing here. You may be able to vary the buffer size to figure it out. Note that this is not the same as the message size. This is the total queue size. Any MQ has to have a large buffer even if it cycles some messages to disk.

You might also find some of the ram allocation is for Unit of Work chatter, and other housekeeping that results from multiple clients.

Speaking of UoW, I certainly hope you have taken the Asynchronous problems into account for any transactions that might be involved in your multi-client solution. An answer that mostly works in my books is a bad answer. You should take pains to prove that your async solution cant be crashed. Because in 6 months if it goes down you will have a hell of a time remembering that it is possible in this one little place in your architecture. You put queues in to preserve sync. What you are doing is potentially playing with fire. Be careful.